# Share a model between Azure and SQL Repositories

Tags: sql, entity-framework, azure, repository, abstraction

I have a set of entities that I would like to persist via the repository pattern.

Vanilla SQL is pretty straight forward, write some methods that have queries that take/return the entities.

Azure table storage is also pretty straight forward, except that most of the implementations I have seen want the entities to be decended from some common Azure base class. (TableServiceEntity etc)

EF works as well, but also wants to own a bit more of the entities.

Is there a good way to abstract away both the SQL and Azure table stuff so that the entities can be persisted either way?

Bidirectional support is not really needed, we are just going to have two different deployment types that need to be supported.

I would like the models to be as agnostic as possible of the repository they are being persisted in, with as few dependancies (none?!) if possible.

Comment: What I want to avoid is where we currently are : We have some agnostic models, and implementation specific models, and they know how to construct each other, but this is a huge PITA

Comment: We started using ValueInjecter and Automapper to get between the models, and that significantly reduces the issue, but I still don't like the overall concept.

Answer (score 2):

This is doable.  I've helped architect this for a client on a decently large scale.

1) Do not inherit from TableServiceEntity but instead implement the following attribute on your entities:

```
[DataServiceKey(new string[] { "PartitionKey", "RowKey" }), Serializable]
```

Also, implement some sort of an interface on your entities that provides PartitionKey,RowKey, and Timestamp to your entities.

```
public interface ITableEntity
{
    string PartitionKey { get; set; }
    string RowKey { get; set; }
    DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

At least this approach will allow you to have your own inheritance strategy for your own entities and not be restricted due to lack of multi-inheritance.  Try to have PartitionKey and RowKey simply provide a pass-through to the real key properties instead of duplicating the keys.

```
public string PartitionKey
{
       get
       {
          return this.Id;
       }
       set
       {
         this.Id = value;
       }
}
```

2) Do realize that you will have two types of repositories in your system: relational-specific and ATS-specific.

3) You can generate your entities via EDMX and use partial classes to inject them with ITableEntity and DataServiceKey attribute

4) At some point you will need your ATS-specific repositories to do some transformations of your entities for persistence's sake, because of the way you'll be saving data into ATS is not the way you'll want it modeled in your domain (this especially relates to hierarchical or relational data)

HTH